# Web Service application in Delphi 2007

Tags: web-services, delphi, client

created and deployed a Web service application in a virtual directory using IIS 6.1. The client application works fine on the same machine. But it is not working in another machine where the client application is copied manually. Can any one help what went wrong?

In Internet explorer, The XML file is displayed in the same machine. But from other machine, 'Un able to open the page' error occurs.

Suggestions please...

Regards,
Baskaran A.

Comment: So in the webserver self you can call the webservice from your client app and from IE without problems, but from another machine IE shows the webservice is working, but the client app fails? I would recommend debugging the client app first because it is fair to assume that the problem lies there, not in the webservice. Only look at the webservice if you conclude otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your firewall settings? Can you open other pages that are served by the same IIS webserver?

Answer (score 1):

My first 2 guesses would be:

1) Firewall settings, as previously mentioned.

2) The client app has a hard coded path in it somewhere that ought to be a relative path or, perhaps a URL. Something along the lines of 127.0.0.1 or localhost or C:\... within the app or in its configuration file(s).